# ValueError at /plants/plants/ too many values to unpack (expected 2) when using django_filters

Tags: html, django, django-templates, django-filter, django-filters

Hej!

I'm having trouble with my django filter.
When I put {{myFilter}} in the template I only get an ObjectNumber and when I put {{myFilter.form}} I get the error:

ValueError at /plants/plants/

too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Does anyone have an idea what's going on?

```
# views.py

def plants_view(request):
    plants = Plant.objects.all()

    myFilter = PlantFilter(plants)

    context = {"plants": plants, "myFilter": myFilter}

    return render(request, 'plants/search_table.html', context)
```

```
# filters.py

class PlantFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Plant
        fields = ['name',]
```

it doesn't matter if I use  `fields = [ ]`  or `fields = '__all__'` .

```
template.html

{% extends "landing/base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% load i18n %}
{% load admin_urls %}
{% block page-title %} {%translate "View Plants" %} {% endblock %}
{% block head %}
<link href="{% static 'landing/vendor/tabulator/dist/css/tabulator.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{% static 'landing/vendor/tabulator/dist/css/bootstrap/tabulator_bootstrap4.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

        <br>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card card-body">

                    <form method="get">
                        {{myFilter.form}}

                        <button class="btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
                    </form>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </br>
```

```
# models.py
class Plant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=200
    )
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}"

    def serialize(self):
        return {
            "Name": self.name
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you follow the documentation on [this page](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/usage.html#the-view) ?

**views.py**

```
def plants_view(request):
    plants = Plant.objects.all()

    myFilter = PlantFilter(request.GET, queryset=plants)

    context = {"plants": plants, "myFilter": myFilter}

    return render(request, 'plants/search_table.html', context)
```

**template.html**

```
<form method="get">
    {{ myFilter.form.as_p }}
    <button class="btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Totally forgot that. 

And maybe related: Do you know how to add M2M relationships to the filter?

Comment: Happy to help ! I think it's pretty straightforward, you just have to add the name of the field into the `fields` list in your filter. But you can find more information in the docs as always (https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filters.html#modelmultiplechoicefilter)

Comment: This only works in one direction. I have some models with a foreign key to the model Plant, which do not occure in the filters.

Comment: Oh I see, so you would have to declare a custom field in your filter and use a method to indicate how to filter it. See here https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filters.html#method

Comment: I have another m2m related question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69448497/django-manytomany-m2m-relationship-in-result-table) your help would be very welcome. Seems I have an issue with my reasoning today :D